# Which other programming language has similarity to Java?

Tags: java

I am a Java professional. Now I like to move other programming language. Can anybody suggest me which programming language would be better to digest soon and language has web devlopment features .I am interested in web-devlopment.

Comment: This is a dupe of many similar questions - e.g. just search for "learn language after java". Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316243/which-programming-language-to-learn-now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# - web-development is very good (Just look at this website) and the code is 'similar' to java.

Below provides a good example of how to approach the transition

http://www.25hoursaday.com/CsharpVsJava.html

> The C# language is an object-oriented
>   language that is aimed at enabling
>   programmers to quickly build a wide
>   range of applications for the
>   Microsoft .NET platform. The goal of
>   C# and the .NET platform is to shorten
>   development time by freeing the
>   developer from worrying about several
>   low level plumbing issues such as
>   memory management, type safety issues,
>   building low level libraries, array
>   boundschecking , etc. thus allowing
>   developers to actually spend their
>   time and energy working on their
>   application and business logic
>   instead. As a Java developer the
>   previous sentence could be described
>   as "a short description of the Java
>   language and platform" if the words C#
>   and the .NET platform were replaced
>   with words Java and the Java platform.

Answer (score 3):

Why not look at [Grails](http://www.grails.org/) ? It's based on Groovy (a JVM/Java language, so you can leverage off your Java knowledge) and allows web development in a RoR fashion.

Answer (score 2):

[Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) is a general purpose language which runs on the JVM, so you can use your existing Java knowledge. Also take a look [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/1305#Java).

It has a web framework called [Lift](http://liftweb.net/).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add another programming language to your capabilities, I'd recommend C# as well, because it's not related to Java (but close enough to re-use your existing skills).

If you need something else because you want to dig into web development - why not look at the Google Web Toolkit (GWT) and create javascript based web application with Java language only?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org). You can use all Java API with this elegant language.

Answer (score 0):

I think C# programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Probably C#.

It allows web-development using Asp.net, which is a pretty popular platform.

Also, C# was, I believe, based on Java, so it has a lot of the same ideas.

Answer (score 0):

While hated by most Java developers (or developers in general), I would prefer JavaFX... it is VERY easy to learn if you have some Java knowledge (you can easily learn the language itself within less than 3 days), and it is designed for RIAs, though you can use it as a full replacement for Java.

[Learning the JavaFX Script Programming Language](http://java.sun.com/javafx/1/tutorials/core/)

is a good place to start.

Oh, and one nice thing about JavaFX: You can use all existing Java APIs from within JavaFX (afaik).